# Generate a txt in php with header and detail

Tags: php

I want to generate reports in PHP txt.

But I don't get the desired result. I need you to show me only the header once. And he repeats it to me.

This is my code:

```
 $sqlPol = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM polizasap_enc a
                            RIGHT join polizasap_det b
                            on a.id_Rec = b.id_Rec");
$file = 'datos.txt';
$jump = "\r\n";
$separator = "  ";

$fp = fopen($file , 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");;

foreach ($sqlPol as $key => $row) {

    $registroCab = $row['tipoRegistro'] . $separator . $row['claseDoc'] . 
    $separator . $row['fechaDoc'] . $separator  . $row['fechaCont'].  
    $separator  . $row['referencia']. $separator . $row['texto']. $jump;

    $registroDet = $row['tpoRegistro'] . $separator . $row['ctaContable'] . 
    $separator . $row['importe'] . $separator  . $row['moneda']. $separator  
    . $row['posPre']. $separator . $row['txtPosicion']. $jump;

    fwrite($fp, $registroCab.$registroDet);
}
fclose($fp);
```

what i get / what i need
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on how to ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances on getting an answer

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Does the first row of your database have what you are calling "headers"?

Comment: The header comes in the database and changes each 2 records